# How to fork two git branches around failed merge

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, revert, git-revert

I have the following situation in my git repository at the moment.

```
HEAD -- 0 -- 1 -- ... -- 3 -- 5 master
         \-- 2 -- ... -- 4 --/  branch-1
```

The branch "branch-1" has been forked from the master some time ago (see commit 5).

At commit 0 I wanted to merge it back to master but all changes that had happened in master between commits 1 and 3 were overwritten. Effectively creating

```
0 -- 2 -- ... -- 4 -- 5 master
```

Since my colleagues could not continue their work on this state I have reverted the merge commit. Thus I did set HEAD to be the same as 1. The command used would be "git revert -m 2 0".

But now I would like my changes merged back in again. This time I hope it will be successful. I need to create something like:

```
-2 -- HEAD -- 0 -- 1 -- ... -- 3 -- 5 master
  \            \-- 2 -- ... -- 4 --/
   \--- -1 ------/
```

This would be a new commit -1 that avoids the failed merge 0 and goes back in at the clean state I had (the clean state I achieved by reverting) prior to the merge.

However just trying to merge 2 to HEAD does not work. I think this is because they are already merged at 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you used `git revert` instead of `git reset --HARD`. `git revert` creates a new commit that redoes the changes of the previous commit. `git reset` does the same, but not by creating a new commit, but by throwing away the faulty commit. Because of that the faulty commit still sits in your history.

Merging 2 to HEAD doesnt work, because you are trying to merge with your own history. It is like trying to merge 4 into 2.

What you need to do is, throw away 0 and make a new one.

First, reset master back to 1 using:

```
git reset --HARD 1
```

Then, reach a clean, merge-ready state there (you can do commits if you need to).

After that, make sure branch-1 points to 2:

```
git checkout branch-1
git reset --HARD 2
```

Reach a clean, merge-ready state there too.
Then, merge them both:

```
git checkout master
git merge branch-1
```

Check the result of the merge. If it didnt work as you want, start over by reseting master and branch-1 again. If you can't get merge working, you might also try a rebase. This will flatten your history to a look like that:

```
2' -- .. -- 4' -- 1 -- .. -- 3 -- 5
```

After you merged or rebased the two branches together, you may rebase any changes that were introduced after the reverted commit (Replace `2'` with the most current commit of the new merge/rebase you created, dont use HEAD as it will change once the command runs):

```
git rebase 2' -2
```

After that, your history should look like that:

```
-2' -- .. -- 2' -- .. -- 4' -- 1 -- .. -- 3 -- 5
```

Or, if you merged instead of rebase:

```
-2' -- .. -- 0' -- 1 -- ... -- 3 -- 5
              \ -- 2 -- ... -- 4 --/
```